# How to fix OpenGL Co-ordinate System in SFML?

Tags: c++, opengl, c, sfml, perspective

My OpenGL setup is somehow configured to work like so:

```
(-1, 1) (0, 1) (1, 1)
(-1, 0) (0, 0) (1, 0)
(-1, -1) (0, -1) (1, -1)
```

How do I configure it so that it works like so:

```
(0, 0) (SW/2, 0) (SW, 0)
(0, SH/2) (SW/2, SH/2) (SW, SH/2)
(0, SH) (SW/2, SH) (SW/2, SH)
```

SW as Screen Width.
SH as Screen Height.

This solution would have to fix the problem of I can't translate significantly(>1) on the Z axis. Depth doesn't seem to be working either. The Perspective code I'm using is that of my WORKING GLUT OpenGL code which has a cool 3d grid and camera system etc. But my OpenGL setup doesn't seem to work with SFML.

Help me guys. :(

Thanks in advance. :)

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <SFML/OpenGL.hpp>
#include "ResourcePath.hpp" //Mac-only

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>

double screen_width = 640.f;
double screen_height = 480.f;

int main (int argc, const char **argv) {
    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.depthBits         = 24;
    settings.stencilBits       = 8;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 2;
    sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(screen_width, screen_height, 32), "SFML OpenGL", sf::Style::Close, settings);

    window.setActive();

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

    glViewport(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    //glOrtho(0.0f, screen_width, screen_height, 0.0f, -100.0f, 100.0f);
    gluPerspective(45.0f, (double) screen_width / (double) screen_height , 0.f, 100.f);

    glClearColor(0.f, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f); //blue

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            switch (event.type) {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    window.close();
                    break;

            }

            switch (event.key.code) {
                case sf::Keyboard::Escape:
                    window.close();
                    break;
                case 'W':
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    break;
                case 'A':
                    break;
                case 'D':
                    break;
            }
        }

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glTranslatef(0.f, 0.f, 0.f);

        glPushMatrix();

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);

        glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(-1.f, 1.f, 0.f);

        glColor3f(0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
        glVertex3f(1.f, 1.f, 0.f);

        glColor3f(1.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glVertex3f(1.f, -1.f, 0.f);

        glColor3f(0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
        glVertex3f(-1.f, -1.f, 0.f);

        glEnd();

        glPopMatrix();

        window.display();
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Hum, sorry but you should tell us what problem you're trying to fix exactly. And what is this "OpenGL setup" you're giving? Maybe illustrate your question with a picture or two?

Comment: The OpenGL setup is the code.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you...

You'll need to change the camera's projection view. Normally, I don't think you use pixel values with a 3D view- unless I'm mistaken. But you can do it fairly easily in 2D:

```
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity ();
glOrtho (0, XSize, YSize, 0, 0, 1);
glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
```

where XSize and YSize are the screen width/heights. Check [here](http://basic4gl.wikispaces.com/2D+Drawing+in+OpenGL) for more on 2D drawing. If you want 3D drawing, you'll probably want to mess around with the gluPerspective method (GLU, not the standard GL)